# Conditional summarise based on condition and repeat monthly for groups, changing date interval range using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to `summarise` and create a column with `case_when` if the following conditions are met for each `id`: sum amount (in a specific month) is at least 10 and at least two distinct dates (in a specific month).

The idea is to create a new column called `2020-01`, with 1 if these conditions are met and 0 otherwise.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-08", "2020-02-18", "2020-02-18", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02")),
id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
amount = c(1, 5, 5, 5, 6, 2, 10, 4, 8, 10, 6, 5, 5, 1, 6, 2, 5, 5)
)
```

To do so, I can create a vector containing all the `ids` that fulfill this condition as stated below:

```
df_2020_01 <- df %>%
filter(date >= as.Date("2020-01-01") & date <= as.Date("2020-01-31")) %>%
group_by(id) %>%
summarise(
    amount_sum = sum(amount),
    date_distinct = n_distinct(date)
) %>%
ungroup() %>%
filter(amount_sum >= 10 & date_distinct >= 2) %>%
select(id)
```

Using this vector, I can create an overview with all `id` and `case_when` with 1 if the if fulfilled this condition:

```
df_overview <- df %>%
distinct(id) %>%
mutate(`2020-01` =
    case_when(id %in% df_2020_01 ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0))
```

Now I want to continue this exercise and create an additional column `2020-02`, but differently: the date interval range (which was defined above being 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-31) should vary - i.e. if the condition was met on the first month (2020-01), the count of `amount_sum` and `date_distinct` should start from scratch (from 2020-02-01 until 2020-02-29) and for the `ids` which had not the condition met on the first month (A and C), the count of `amount_sum` and `date_distinct` should start from scratch (i.e. 2020-01-01 until 2020-02-29).

In this case, `id` A would fulfill this condition, because between 2020-01-01 and 2020-02-29 the `amount_sum` = 16 and `date_distinct` = 3.

The idea is to continue this exercise, but the maximum interval of months should be two. This means that for the third column `2020-03`, if the `id` did not fulfill the requirements on `2020-01` and `2020-02`, the date interval range should be 2020-02-01 to 2020-03-31. If it fulfilled on `2020-01`, the same range would be applied (2020-02-01 to 2020-03-31). But if the `id` fulfilled the requirements on `2020-02`, the date interval range would be only 2020-03-01 to 2020-03-31.

To recap:
I need to create a data frame with unique `ids`, with a `year-month` column (for all dates contained on my data set) that should receive a 1 if these conditions are met (and 0 otherwise):

- `amount_sum` (in a specific month) >= 10 and `date_distinct` (in a specific month) >= 2 (`group_by` = `id`).
- The date interval range should be of 1 or 2 months (depending if the condition was fulfilled on the previous month).
- If the condition was fulfilled on the previous month, the next month should restart the sum of `amount_sum` and `date_distinct` from zero (for one month/for the analysed month). If not, the date interval range sum for variables `amount_sum` and `date_distinct` should be of two months.

Desired output:

```
  id 2020-01 2020-02 2020-03
  A        0       1       0
  B        1       0       1
  C        0       1       1
```

I hope I was clear enough explaining my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: @akrun just added the desired output. Please note that I've edited the amounts above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**revised new answer** (starts after 2 months)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


df <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-08", "2020-02-18", "2020-02-18", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02")),
  id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  amount = c(1, 5, 5, 5, 6, 2, 10, 4, 8, 10, 6, 5, 5, 1, 6, 2, 5, 5)
)

# function to calculate if condition is met for a given months range
calc_id <- function(.dat, m1, m2 = NULL) {
  
  extr_date <- m1
  
  if(is.null(m2)) {
    m2 <- extr_date  
  } else {
    m2 <- extr_date %m-% months(m2) 
  }
  
  dat_end <- extr_date %m+% months(1) 
  dat_start <- m2
  
  temp1 <- .dat %>%
    filter(date < dat_end,
           date >= dat_start)
  
  if (nrow(temp1) == 0) return(NA)
  
  temp2 <- temp1 %>% 
    summarise(
      amount_sum = sum(amount),
      date_distinct = n_distinct(date)
    ) %>%
    filter(amount_sum >= 10 & date_distinct >= 2)
  
  if (nrow(temp2) > 0) {
    return(1)
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
  
} 

# function which decides which months range to choose
comb_calc <- function(.dat, m, mdiff) {
  
  lag_date <- m  %m-% months(1) 
  lag_date2 <- m  %m-% months(2) 
  
  # added condition to return NA if one of the two preceeding month is NA
  if (is.na(calc_id(.dat, lag_date2)) || is.na(calc_id(.dat, lag_date))) {
    
    return(NA)
    
  } else if (calc_id(.dat, lag_date) == 0) {
    
    calc_id(.dat, m1 = m, m2 = mdiff)
    
  } else {
    
    calc_id(.dat, m1 = m)
    
  }
  

}


# rearrange data
df %>% 
  nest_by(id) %>% 
  crossing(Date = floor_date(df$date, "month")) %>% 
  rowwise(id) %>% 
  # call comb_calc and choose number of months (here 2)
  mutate(res = comb_calc(data, Date, 2)) %>% 
  select(-data) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Date,
              values_from = res) %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_sub(., 1, 7), matches("^\\d{4}-\\d{2}"))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   id    `2020-01` `2020-02` `2020-03`
#>   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 A            NA        NA         0
#> 2 B            NA        NA         1
#> 3 C            NA        NA         1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**new answer** (works for custom number of month)

To account for not only two but any possible amount of month to be considered I changed to approach. It makes use of two custom functions.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-08", "2020-02-18", "2020-02-18", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02")),
  id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  amount = c(1, 5, 5, 5, 6, 2, 10, 4, 8, 10, 6, 5, 5, 1, 6, 2, 5, 5)
)

# function to calculate if condition is met for a given months range
calc_id <- function(.dat, m1, m2 = NULL) {
  
  extr_date <- m1
  
  if(is.null(m2)) {
    m2 <- extr_date  
  } else {
    m2 <- extr_date %m-% months(m2) 
  }
  
  dat_end <- extr_date %m+% months(1) 
  dat_start <- m2
  
  temp1 <- .dat %>%
    filter(date < dat_end,
           date >= dat_start)
  
  if (nrow(temp1) == 0) return(NA)
  
  temp2 <- temp1 %>% 
    summarise(
      amount_sum = sum(amount),
      date_distinct = n_distinct(date)
    ) %>%
    filter(amount_sum >= 10 & date_distinct >= 2)
  
  if (nrow(temp2) > 0) {
    return(1)
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
  
} 

# function which decides which months range to choose
comb_calc <- function(.dat, m, mdiff) {
  
  lag_date <- m  %m-% months(1) 
  
  if (!is.na(calc_id(.dat, lag_date)) && calc_id(.dat, lag_date) == 0) {
    
    calc_id(.dat, m1 = m, m2 = mdiff)
    
  } else {
    
    calc_id(.dat, m1 = m)
    
  }
}


# rearrange data
df %>% 
  nest_by(id) %>% 
  crossing(Date = floor_date(df$date, "month")) %>% 
  rowwise(id) %>% 
  # call comb_calc and choose number of months (here 2)
  mutate(res = comb_calc(data, Date, 2)) %>% 
  select(-data) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Date,
              values_from = res,
              values_fill = 0) %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_sub(., 1, 7), matches("^\\d{4}-\\d{2}"))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   id    `2020-01` `2020-02` `2020-03`
#>   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 A             0         1         0
#> 2 B             1         0         1
#> 3 C             0         1         1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**old answer** (works for window of two months)

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-08", "2020-02-18", "2020-02-18", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02")),
  id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  amount = c(1, 5, 5, 5, 6, 2, 10, 4, 8, 10, 6, 5, 5, 1, 6, 2, 5, 5)
)

calc_id <- function(.dat) {
  
  .dat %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(
      amount_sum = sum(amount),
      date_distinct = n_distinct(date)
    ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    filter(amount_sum >= 10 & date_distinct >= 2) %>%
    pull(id)
  
}

df %>% 
  mutate(month = paste(lubridate::year(date), lubridate::month(date), sep = "-")) %>% 
  nest_by(month) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(data2 = lag(data)) %>% 
  rowwise(month) %>% 
  mutate(data2 = list(bind_rows(data, data2)),
         res = list(calc_id(data)), 
         id = list(calc_id(data2))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(res2 = lag(res, default = list(""))) %>% 
  unnest(res) %>% 
  unnest(res2) %>% 
  unnest(id) %>% 
  filter(! id == res2) %>% 
  select(month, id) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(val = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = month,
              values_from = val,
              values_fill = 0) %>% 
  arrange(id)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   id    `2020-1` `2020-2` `2020-3`
#>   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 A            0        1        0
#> 2 B            1        0        1
#> 3 C            0        1        1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Only one question: still trying to understand the second part. If I would like to increase the date interval period from 2 to 12 months (for calculating `amount_sum` and `date_distinct ` fulfillment), would it be possible?

Comment: Please check my revised answer.

Comment: Thank you for your revised answer - almost there! Two problems: (1) after `pivot_wider`, the column order gets messy.  Tried to correct it afterwards with `select(order(colnames(.)))` but it did not work. Maybe it is necessary to add a 0 between the year and the month between 1-9 (e.g. 2019-09)? Is it possible to add a 0 for the months with only one digit (i.e. months 01-09)? (2) Is it possible to start computing only after specific number of months - i.e. for the example above (2 months only), to count only from the third month and on, and then monthly (i.e. 2020-03, 2020-04)?

Comment: Regarding (1) I updated the code it should work now, but if not please provide some more example data where the ordering is messed up after applying `pivot_wider`. Regarding (2) I added an additional version which starts calculating after two months. You can add any kind of logic to the `comb_calc` function.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to adapt this code to my other question? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817328/cumulative-sum-with-reset-option-if-multiple-conditions-are-met

Comment: @User I could look into it, but I am kinda surprised that my answer on your original question here got "unaccept", although it solves your question (especially in the absence of other, better answers).

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the status to "Unanswered" because it did not work in the end for some specific cases. I will put it again as answered because for the particular example it worked. For a more general case, as mentioned on my other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817328/cumulative-sum-with-reset-option-if-multiple-conditions-are-met), it did not work.